# implement WebServices on Android

Tags: android, web-services, publish, server-side

I have to integrate an existing javabased Framework (whith different components which communicate via SOAP) in my Android. Every Component needs to receive and send SOAP-Messages, needs to act as a Server.

Is it true that Android OS < 2.0 does not support Server functionalities? What would be the min. Version?

Which framework can i use? I only found a few kSOAP examples for the client side, but none for servers.

Thanks for every hint, link, idea... help:)
Fabi

Comment: are all components meant to be on the same device?

Comment: no. one component is on a Server, 2 are on my android.

Answer (score 0):

You best bet would be to run e.g. jetty as a server on Android but I would seriously reconsider your architecture. Why do the devices need to act as server? Are they being contacted in a pull way by another device or server?

Answer (score 0):

yeah you're right... reconsidering the architecture would be best. But i can't change the existing framework which comnponents i have to use.(yes, a pull way communication is implemented) 
Thanks for your help. But i just decided to use the framework by implementing a polling-service. A lot of extra work... but it will do it:)
fabi